# Assembly:Is there any advantage of passing arguments to a function in using stack?

Tags: assembly, stack, masm, procedure

I was wondering if there was any advantage of passing arguments to functions using stack, in assembly language. 
  Here is what I mean:

```
readString PROTO :DWORD ;Prototype for function
;Now we call the function by moving a DWORD value into eax and pushing eax
mov eax, FAD37EABh
push eax
CALL readString
```

Is there any advantage of using this method over the following?

```
INVOKE readString, FAD37EABh
```

Regards,

Devjeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no difference in the final code, but it is very convenient. It's a macro which automatically checks if arguments type match, therefore helping you spotting errors. Of course, `invoke readString, eax` or `push eax; call readString` are almost the same, but suppose you need to call Win32'a API with their thousands of parameters:

```
    push NULL
    push hInst
    push NULL
    push NULL
    push 200
    push 300
    push CW_USEDEFAULT
    push CW_USEDEFAULT
    push WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
    push addr Appame
    push addr Classame
    push WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    call CreateWindowEx
```

```
    INVOKE CreateWindowEx,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,ADDR ClassName,ADDR AppName,\
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,\
           CW_USEDEFAULT,300,200,NULL,NULL,\
           hInst,NULL
```

In this case uning `invoke` is much more helpful and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Not really; `invoke` is basically just a built-in macro that will expand to pretty much the same code anyway.

Comment: @devjeetroy: I generally prefer `invoke` syntax, but there are people who disagree. Windows code, in particular, gets really *long* if you do all the pushes explicitly (e.g., a single call to CreateFile ends up ~20 lines long).